# MySQL -- Updating the login time in my data base

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently working on a project where I need to store information in a database for member login page. Currently, I am working on storing the time the user enters their credentials. It keeps popping up with "Duplicate entry '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for key 'PRIMARY'", which I understand everything except for why my time will not process as an actual time... Below the section of  my code that I am working with... maybe something is wrong? Or is there a better way to call the current timestamp than what I am doing.

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
or die("Failed to connect");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userlogin']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userpassword']);
    $today = date("F j, Y, h:i:s A"); 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE loginName = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'"; //checks for user in database
    //--password = SHA2(CONCAT('bar','paz'),512)";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); //shoots an error if something is wrong
    if($result->num_rows < 1) // if the username/password is incorrect then an error message appears
       {
        echo "Invalid username/password combination. Please try again.";
       }
    else
       {
        echo "Welcome."; //Successful
        $today = date("F j, Y, h:i:s A"); 
        header('Location: thankspage.html');
     $sql = " INSERT INTO Login (loginName,loginTime) 
       VALUES ('$username', '$today' ) "; // creates the login time.
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die ($mysqli->error); // shoots an error if i did something wrong.
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't see where you set the value of loginTime from your code.

Comment: Have you tried using `NOW()` in your `INSERT` statement? Bit cleaner than using `date`

Comment: >> $sql = "SELECT * FROM Member WHERE loginName = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";

http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change the datetime format

```
$today = date("F j, Y, h:i:s A");
```

to a proper one

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Here is **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dnhT08)** demo

or ditch `$today` altogether and use `NOW()` on MySQL side (if the timezone setting is the same as on the web server)

```sql
INSERT INTO Login (loginName, loginTime) VALUES ('$username', NOW())
                                                              ^^^^^
```

**On a side note:** since you already using `mysqli` consider to learn and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of interpolating query strings, which leaves you wide open to sql injections.

Comment: I appreciate it the help! I had tried this earlier but my syntax was goofed up when I first started to write my code. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. But if your date column is `timestamp` type. It should more easy and it should show your time according to you current time zone. If `dates` is a date column then I set like

```
  `dates` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And every time your insert or update query, you should use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Suppose

```
 INSERT INTO Login (loginName,loginTime) VALUES ('$username', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```